# fortran undefined reference to lnblnk getpid dtime etime

Tags: fortran, linker-errors, gfortran

I am trying to port some old fortran code.  It will compile without error, and without warnings, using the Intel compiler ifort.
When I try to use gfortran, specifically 4.3.4 and gfortran-4.8, I receive errors for undefined reference for the functions LNBLNK_ GETPID_ DTIME_ and ETIME_.
I google this problem and it seems like LNBLNK is supposed to be an intrinsic function for gfortran.  Anyone know a way around this problem?

I suppose i can write my own LNBLNK function since it's simple.  For ETIME and DTIME I could comment those out they are not a necessity, but GETPID I do need.

edit:  i am compiling over 100 files together on a single `gfortran-4.8` command.  I edited only those files that had `LNBLNK` mentioned as undefined reference and replaced it with `LEN_TRIM`.  This solved those undefined reference errors, however if i do a `grep` on all the files being compiled I see at least 10 others still using `LNBLNK` and it is successfully compiling past this specific `undefined reference to LNKBLNK` error.
what would cause this?
could this be a bug with gfortran?

edit #2

it seems code like this works:  `WRITE(6,*) mystring(1:LNBLNK(mystring))`

however any files that use the `LNBLNK` command like this below result in the compiler error:

```
INTEGER LNBLNK
EXTERNAL LNBLNK
INTEGER POS

POS = LNBLNK( mystring )
```

it results in this specific compiler error

```
/tmp/ccsdBgxK.o: In function `whatever_':
whatever.f:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `lnblnk_'
```

Comment: Always use [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions to get dome attention.

Comment: You should show the commands you execute if you want the explanation . You should also show the exact error messages. Those functions are indeed intrinsic procedures of gfortran. But don't use `4.3.4`, it is too old for serious usage.

Comment: i updated the information above.

Answer (score 0):

thank you Vlad.  that link helped me solve the problem for DTIME and ETIME.

in the old code it was doing this, which works with the Intel ifort compiler:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION DTIME
EXTERNAL DTIME
```

if I simply remove the `EXTERNAL DTIME` then that will solve the specific `undefined reference` error for this function for both the Intel ifort compiler and for the gnu gfortran-4.8.

However, for gfortran-4.8 I can also comment out the `DOUBLE PRECISION DTIME` and it will compile but it will cause an error on the Intel ifort compiler.  And if I comment out both those and use only `INTRINSIC DTIME` then that will work for gfortran but will result in an error for ifort.

So the solution seems to only explicitly declare the return value of the function, which was `DOUBLE PRECISON DTIME`  or  `INTEGER LNBLNK`  and definitely do NOT use the `EXTERNAL` nor `INSTRINSIC` declarations.

Note:  my solution for `LNBLNK` was to replace every occurrence of it with `LEN_TRIM`.  And any occurrence of `INTEGER LNBLNK` and `EXTERNAL LNBLNK` was removed.